# How to store linux command output into a variable in puppet

Tags: linux, bash, puppet, puppet-enterprise

Is it possible to store a linux command result in variable?

I am trying to store an encrypted value in a variable. To encrypt I am using base64 command. To store it in variable, I am using generate method. But I am not able to store a value.

```
$secretvalue    = generate("/bin/bash","-c","/usr/bin/echo ${password} | /usr/bin/base64")
```

Comment: base64 is **not** an encryption.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to execute any command on Puppet Master server you can use `inline_template` function with ERB template inside and Ruby code for execute shell command:

```
$password = "12345"

$secretvalue = inline_template("<%= `/bin/echo ${password} | /usr/bin/base64` %>")

notify { "STDOUT: ${secretvalue}": }
```

P.S.
  If you just want to encode string to Base64 format you can import [puppetlabs-stdlib](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-stdlib) module and use `base64` function from it:

```
$secretvalue = base64('encode', $password)
```

Comment: Is it possible to launch some bash command on puppet client host and save it into variable?

Comment: Yes, but only through your custom `facts`.